# MySQL Incorrect DateTime Value 2005

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a web app that collect a simple poll data from my friends. I wanna run a SELECT query to get names based on when the date and month they run put a vote on a poll.

So this is my queries:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_votedata 
WHERE votersname = "Jack Ryan" 
AND targetname = "Bill Murray"
AND votetype = "Friends" 
AND MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH(2017-10-02) 
AND YEAR(timestamp) = YEAR(2017-10-02)
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, it returns error like this (I'm using HeidiSQL):

[image]

Wasn't MySQL datetime value is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:S'? So, it should be run OK right? Since my query only select the year and month only...

So what is wrong exactly?

Comment: You need single quotes around the date, i.e. use `MONTH('2017-10-02')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date constants should be quoted, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_votedata 
WHERE votersname = 'Jack Ryan'
  AND targetname = 'Bill Murray'
  AND votetype = 'Friends'
  AND MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH('2017-10-02') 
  AND YEAR(timestamp) = YEAR('2017-10-02')
```

It was evaluating the `20107 - 10 - 2` expression and used the result as the argument to the function, which was not the correct data type...

Comment: I think you should vote to close this question as being a typo.

Comment: Ok... thank you... I should be more careful with my query